# Реализация скроллбара с ползунком на js и php

Tags: javascript, php

Задаешь значение двум переменным от 1 до 10 например.
И когда перетаскиваешь ползунок он выдает значение от 1 до 10 в зависимости от своего положения, просто текстом на страницу. Буду благодарен за быстрый ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно считать что почти без js

```html
<input type="range" min="-33" max="133" value="22" onchange="val.textContent=this.value">
<label id="val">22</label>
```

```
<?php

    $min=-33;
    $max=133;
    $val=22;

    echo "<input type='range' min='".$min."' max='".$max."' value='".$val."' 
                 onchange='val.textContent=this.value'>
          <label id='val'>".$val."</label>";

?>
```

[http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3eba99da347369dbd739cdb502bdba36a4124e7)

Comment: Спасибо, помогли :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function scrollPos() {
  var div = document.getElementById("block").scrollTop;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = div;
}
```

```css
#block {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 22px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-Y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="block" onscroll="scrollPos()">
  Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя
  Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах
  и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<p id="text">
</p>
```